# Whitespace sensitive FParsec

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm trying to implement a whitespace sensitive parser using FParsec, and I'm starting off with the baby step of defining a function which will parse lines of text that start with `n` chars of whitespace.

Here's what I have so far:

```
let test: Parser<string list,int>
  = let manyNSatisfy i p = manyMinMaxSatisfy i i p

    let p = fun (stream:CharStream<int>) ->
      let state = stream.UserState

      // Should fail softly if `state` chars wasn't parsed
      let result = attempt <| manyNSatisfy state (System.Char.IsWhiteSpace) <| stream

      if result.Status <> Ok 
        then result
        else restOfLine false <| stream

    sepBy p newline
```

My issue is that when I run

`runParserOnString test 1 "test" " hi\n there\nyou" |> printfn "%A"`

I get an error on "you". I was under the impression that `attempt` would backtrack any state changes, and returning `Error` as my status would give me soft failure.

How do I get `["hi"; "there"]` back from my parser?

Comment: This wiki-page contains two FParsec parser implementations for a simple grammar with significant whitespace: https://bitbucket.org/fparsec/main/wiki/Parsing%20indentation-based%20syntax%20with%20FParsec

Answer (score 3):

Oh dear, how embarrassing.

I wanted `sepEndBy`, which is to say that I should terminate the parse on the separator.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more idiomatic. I have hard-coded `1`, but it's easy to extract as parameter.

```
let skipManyNSatisfy i = skipManyMinMaxSatisfy i i
let pMyText =
    (                                               // 1st rule
        skipManyNSatisfy 1 System.Char.IsWhiteSpace // skip an arbitrary # of WhiteSpaces
        >>. restOfLine false |>> Some               // return the rest as Option
    )
    <|>                                             // If the 1st rule failed...
    (                                               // 2nd rule
        skipRestOfLine false                        // skip till the end of the line
        >>. preturn None                            // no result
    )
    |> sepBy <| newline                             // Wrap both rules, separated by newLine
    |>> Seq.choose id                               // Out of received string option seq, select only Some()
```

Comment: thanks, although that does change the semantics of what I was doing drastically. I don't want / need to skip lines. The reason for the low-level implementation was to get at that state variable.

Comment: @Khanzor well, if your primary goal is making a parser for something similar to F# syntax, then maybe you need to count spaces and then pass it to the syntax checker for the rest of the job, correct?